# How to express the following batch steps in a single cmd invocation?

Tags: batch-file, dos

Assume I have steps in a batch file as follows.

```
set dir=%CD%
cd ..\notes
dir /b *.tex > %dir%\log.txt
cd %dir%
```

How to express these steps in a single `cmd` call?

I attempted to call as follows

```
cmd /c set dir=%CD% cd ..\notes dir /b *.tex > %dir%\log.txt cd %dir%
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
cmd /c "pushd ..\notes & dir /b *.tex > %cd%\log.txt & popd"
```

Comment: Never used pushd and popd (read about them once).  Nicely done :)